# Javascript More/Less button sliding animation?

Tags: javascript

I only have very basic knowledge on Javascript and I want to be able to make my more/less button that displays/hides content be an animated slide instead of an instant change. Here is  the Javascript I currently have:

```
function doMenu(item) {
    obj=document.getElementById(item);
    col=document.getElementById("x" + item);
    if (obj.style.display=="none") {
        obj.style.display="block";
        col.innerHTML="[-] Less";
    } else {
        obj.style.display="none";
        col.innerHTML="[+] More";
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can change this Javascript to slide instead?

**EDIT** An example of the link I use to show/hide content

```
<a href="JavaScript:doMenu('main');" id=xmain>[+] More</a>
```

Comment: You should really look into jQuery and the `.slideToggle()` method...

Comment: @ShaneBlake I see how I could probably use that, I don't know how to incorporate it into my method though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jquery way to do it... (though i didn't have time to test...)

the script :

```
$(function() {     
       $(".moreLess").hide();

       $(".moreLessSwitch").toggle(function() {             
            $(this).html("[-] Less");            
            $(this).prevAll(".moreLess").slideDown();         
       }, function() {            
            $(this).html("[+] More");            
            $(this).prevAll(".moreLess").slideUp();        
       }); 

});
```

the HTML :

```
stuff to always show
<div class="moreLess">stuff to hide...</div>
<div class="moreLessSwitch">[+] More</div>
```

EDIT:   I should never post w/out testing...

Here's the working jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/v9WAr/

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't do anything, the `[+] More` isn't actually a link to call the function, I don't see how it could possibly do anything. Additionally, you're missing a parenthesis on `.toggle(function()`

Comment: @Tory  -  Yes, I was missing a ")", among other things...  But follow the link to the jsFiddle and enjoy...

Comment: I see the working jsfiddle, nicely done... For some reason this won't work for me on my site. Clicking the `[+] More` does nothing even though when I inspect that and the stuff I want to hide, the divs do have the proper classes assigned.

Comment: @Tory - Have you added jQuery to your page?  (if so, I may need to see how your HTML looks, exactly...)

Comment: I'm running it thru a local apache server via WAMP, that does have jQuery right?

Comment: The javascript I was running from my OP worked just fine... Would it matter if I had some divs inside of the `moreLess` div?

Comment: @Tory - So long as the `moreLess` div and the `moreLessSwitch` div are siblings, it should work fine with whatever HTML inside the `moreLess` div...

Comment: I even tried just pasting in the HTML and CSS straight into my code and it doesn't work, I'm a little stumped here.

Comment: @ShaneBlake let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1411/discussion-between-tory-waterman-and-shaneblake)

Comment: Got it working, actually. Because I'm an idiot I didn't actually have jQuery installed.

Comment: @Tory - Glad you got it working...  and there's a bold line between idiot and novice...  ;)

Answer (score 2):

check out the jquery library(slidedown):
[w3 schools jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_effects.asp)-
[jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Comment: Again, I'm kinda new to Javascript (and JQuery), I'm not really sure how to go about using that in my method.

Comment: Don't link to w3schools. Link to the real thing: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/